# I got an error in python 3 about Keyerror

Tags: python

I got this code from udemy course:

```
    def choose_magic(self):
     i = 1
     print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Magic" + bcolors.ENDC)
     for spell in self.magic:
        print(str(i) + ":", spell["name"], "(cost:", str(spell["cost"]) + ")")
        i += 1
```

When I try to call this function I got this error:

```
print(str(i) + ":", spell["name"], "(cost:", str(spell["cost"]) + ")")
KeyError: 'cost'
```

I got this from udemy course and when I try to run return that error.

Comment: Spell doesn't contain key "cost"..

Comment: You can try with method like `spell.get('cost')`, this would return None (as default) if there is no such key 'cost'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spell` dict doesn't have a `"cost"` key.  You'll need to look at where it's initialized (i.e. the members of `self.magic`).

FWIW, this `print` statement:

```
print(str(i) + ":", spell["name"], "(cost:", str(spell["cost"]) + ")")
```

works a lot better in Python 3 as an f-string:

```
print(f"{i}: {spell['name']} (cost: {spell['cost']})")
```

but you still need to sort out that `cost` thing before it'll work.  :)

Comment: First time I got this function:     def get_spell_mp_cost(self, i):
        return self.magic[i]["cost"]

Comment: and than where I call the function is here:    elif index == 1:
        player.choose_magic()
        magic_choice = int(input("Choose Magic: ")) - 1///
        magic_dmg = player.generate_spell_damage(i)///
        spell = player.get_spell_name(magic_choice)///
        cost = player.get_spell_mp_cost(magic_choice)///

        current_mp = player.get_mp()///

Comment: None of that shows me where `self.magic` gets its values.  I'm guessing that one of your spells doesn't have a cost.

Comment: I think here: class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = [bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "Attack" + bcolors.ENDC,
                        bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Magic" + bcolors.ENDC]

Comment: I am new here on coding

Comment: I got yeah you are right thank you very much. One of my spell doesn't have a cost in the dictionary